# memcpy error on struct

Tags: c, struct, memcpy

I'm getting the following error with memcpy. It doesn't give compilation error but doesn't give the result I would imagine. I've never used memcpy before so I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake. I've looked around previous questions but couldn't find one with structures. I can use memcpy on independent variables but just not on structs.

If someone can point out my mistake it'll be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
 struct st{
 char c1[12];
 char c2[32];
 char c3[3];
 char c4[7];
 char c5[13];
 char c6[5];
 char c7[10];
 };
 struct st s;
 char s1[] = "part number";
 char s2[] = "j9uijd9d09fj";
 char s3[] = "abc";
 char s4[] = "seven";
 char s5[] = "aaaaaaaa";
 char s6[] = "ptype";
 char s7[] = "user";
 memcpy(s.c1,s1,sizeof(s.c1));
 memcpy(s.c2,s2,sizeof(s.c2));
 memcpy(s.c3,s3,sizeof(s.c3));
 memcpy(s.c4,s4,sizeof(s.c4));
 memcpy(s.c5,s5,sizeof(s.c5));
 memcpy(s.c6,s6,sizeof(s.c6));
 memcpy(s.c7,s7,sizeof(s.c7));
 printf("%s\n",s.c1);
 printf("%s\n",s.c2);
 printf("%s\n",s.c3);
 printf("%s\n",s.c4);
 printf("%s\n",s.c5);
 printf("%s\n",s.c6);
 printf("%s\n",s.c7);
 return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT I'm getting :

```
part number
j9uijd9d09fj
abcseven
seven
aaaaaaaa
ptypeuser
user
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: You can use memcpy on structs too. I didn't quite understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the size of `c3` in your struct to `4` and `c6` to `6` to allow for the `NULL` terminator.

```
struct st{
    char c1[12];
    char c2[32];
    char c3[4]; /* putting 'abc' which is 4 chars */
    char c4[7];
    char c5[13];
    char c6[6]; /* putting 'ptype' which is 6 chars */
    char c7[10];
};
```

Comment: `c6` also needs another `char`.

Comment: @hmjd - I noticed that just after my initial post. Now corrected.

Comment: @pstrjds 
Thanks a lot!!
Actually i tried making '\0' to '' in a for loop. But I think I made a mistake there as well... :)

Anyways its working now... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`printf` with `%s` prints a null-terminated string. `s3` (and `s6`) in this case has the null-terminating character overwritten by `c` so `printf` stops printing it when it reaches the next one, which is after `seven`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong for two things:

1. `s.c3` is 3 characters in length, so there is no room for the extra NUL byte. That's why you get it concatenated with the next one on printing.
2. In some cases, you are copying more bytes than there is in the original string: `memcpy(s.c2,s2,sizeof(s.c2))` is copying 32 bytes, but the original string is far shorter. That is undefined behaviour.

Probabl you want to use `strcpy()`.

Or even `strncpy`, but beware! this functions does not do what most people think... Read the documentation at least twice before using it.

Answer (score 0):

In the structure the member `c3` is an array of three characters. You then copy *four* characters into it! Remember that strings have an extra character that ends the string, so the string `"abc"` is actually four characters: `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` and the terminator `'\0'`.

The same for the `c6` member of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is the missing NUL-terminator of the character sequences.

A character sequence as you constructor them, is always one character longer then the amount of characters you types in. The additional character at the end is the NUL-terminator.

So the arrays you copy your thing in, need to be one character longer then the amount of characters you want to copy in. For `c3` the amount of characters is too small, causing the NUL-terminator to be missing.

`printf` then prints your string character by character until it sees the NUL-terminator. In case its missing, `printf` just continues reading the memory until it hits the first `0x00`-byte. In this case you are lucky because you are using a structure. Structures are written in one block of memory so `printf` just drops into the next field.

You solve your problem simply by ensuring that the arrays sizes in the structure are always larger then the character sequences you want to copy in.

Comment: NUL terminator. With 1 L only. NULL is a pointer. NUL sometime is used in ASCII nomenclature for the 0 character.

Comment: @user1558399 You should select the answer you consider correct with that green tick to mark the question answered.